# Counting repeating dictionaries, then appending a count key and it's value

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
flist = [
     {'ext' : '.txt', 'name' : 'file1'},
     {'ext' : '.png', 'name' : 'picture1'},
     {'ext' : '.txt', 'name' : 'file1'},
     {'ext' : '.py', 'name' : 'script'},
    ]
```

I want to create a new list which has a count of how many times the item showed up in the first list.

```
summary = []

for item in flist:
     if item not in summary:
            item['count'] = 1
            summary.append(item)
     else:
            item['count'] += 1

for i in summary:
     print i
```

I want the output list to look like this:

```
{'count': 2, 'ext': '.txt', 'name': 'file1'}
{'count': 1, 'ext': '.png', 'name': 'picture1'}
{'count': 1, 'ext': '.py', 'name': 'script'}
```

But what ends up happening is I get all 4 items, with "count: 1". I assume because it's adding count : 1 the first time, which makes that dict unique.

```
{'count': 1, 'ext': '.txt', 'name': 'file1'}
{'count': 1, 'ext': '.png', 'name': 'picture1'}
{'count': 1, 'ext': '.txt', 'name': 'file1'}
{'count': 1, 'ext': '.py', 'name': 'script'}
```

Comment: Hint: `summary.append(item)` only happens when you set `item['count'] = 1`... Were you expecting something else?

Comment: What about using collections.Counter?

Comment: Quickly scanning through the code, I see that you're storing {'ext': '.txt', 'name': 'file1', 'count': 1} into summary then comparing it with {'ext': '.txt', 'name': 'file1'} which, of course, returns False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this with `groupby`,

```
In [76]: from itertools import groupby
In [77]: data = []
In [78]: for g,l in groupby(sorted(flist)):
    ...:     g.update({'count':len(list(l))})
    ...:     data.append(g)
    ...:     

In [79]: print data
Out[79]: 
[{'count': 1, 'ext': '.png', 'name': 'picture1'},
 {'count': 1, 'ext': '.py', 'name': 'script'},
 {'count': 2, 'ext': '.txt', 'name': 'file1'}]
```

Comment: sorted(flist) does not work because you get this: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: @AshishAcharya You are using `python 3.x`, This kind of sort only work in `python2.x`. The OP used python2 here that's why i written a code like this.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul K P, this worked perfectly! I'm below 15 rep so I can't up vote but I appreciate it! Now to take a look at why this works.

Comment: @futurechase you can accept answers instead saying thanks

Comment: @Marzipan Keep in mind, you can only accept one answer

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

1) `item in summary` - You are editing the `item` from `flist` with a count, therefore the original item no longer exists.

2) You only append the initial value, not the sum

```
item['count'] = 1
summary.append(item)
```

You might be interested in the `Counter` object

```
from collections import Counter, namedtuple
File = namedtuple('File', ['name', 'ext'])

flist = [
  File('file1', '.txt'),
  File('picture1', 'png'),
  File('file1', '.txt'),
  File('script', '.py')
  ]

c = Counter()
for f in flist:
  c[f] += 1

for f, count in c.items():
  print(count, f)
```

Output

```
2 File(name='file1', ext='.txt')
1 File(name='picture1', ext='png')
1 File(name='script', ext='.py')
```

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. I actually saw a lot of recommendations to use Counter, but the examples were too different from what I was trying to do. Now this makes sense!

Comment: Welcome. I used a namedtuple because dict objects weren't hashable (a Counter is just a dictionary itself)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` after sort the original list.

```
l = sorted(flist, key=lambda item: item["ext"])

summary = []

for key, value in groupby(l):
    key.update({"count": len(list(value))})
    summary.append(key)
```

Comment: Why you sort based on `"ext"` ??

Comment: @RahulKP To address the problem mentioned by @ Ashish Acharya. So the solution can work on py2 and py3.

Comment: But there is a possiblity to`ext` will be same and diffrent `name` that will come along and the solution may go wrong.

Comment: You can change the lambda function let it be the values of the dict.